# how to fix youtube video in uiwebview from playing behind parent view controller

Tags: ios, youtube, three20, autorotate, ttphotoviewcontroller

I have implemented TTPhotoViewController in my app and it is working fine. However, it seems to have broken the landscape orientation on the the only view controller that rotates in my tabbarcontroller (subclassed). I have also returned NO in `- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` in my subclassed TTphotoviewcontroller and TTThumbviewcontrollers to stop landscape orientation of the photo gallery.

The view controller that previously was able to orientate to landscape plays youtube videos. The view controller loads a list of videos (youtube mobile page) but now when you select a video to play the file plays in the iOS movieplayer in landscape (which is a good thing) but BEHIND the parent view controller which remains in portrait.

I have removed the code to force the video view controller to orientate to landscape and the behaviour persists, which makes me think it is something to do with a file in the Three20 library.

Any ideas?